# Наложение текста при изменении TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Написал такое activity:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PlusMinusOneCounterTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/PlusMinusOneCounterDefaultValue"
    android:textSize="75sp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/PlusOneButton"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/PlusOneButtonText"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MinusOneButton"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/MinusOneButtonText"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</LinearLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Идея в том, что бы были две кнопки на весь экран, а под ними собственно значение.
Проблема в том, что при изменении значения `TextView`, старое значение не стирается, а накладывается на новое. Сообственно как можно этого избежать?

Пробывал `invalidate()` на `RelativeLayout` и `TextView`, не помогло :(

UPD. Код изменения текста:

```
private void setCounterTextViewValue( Integer _newValue )
{
    if( m_сounterTextView == null )
        m_сounterTextView = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.PlusMinusOneCounterTextView );

    m_сounterTextView.setText( _newValue.toString() );
}
```

UPD. Привязка кнопке - вот так:

```
Button plusOneButton = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.PlusOneButton );
plusOneButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v )
        {
              try
              {
                  m_plusMinusOneCounter.increment();
                  setCounterTextViewValue( m_plusMinusOneCounter.getValue() );

              }
              catch ( LessThanMinValueException | MoreThanMaxValueException e )
              {
                  // Do nothing
              }
          }
    }
);
```

Похоже на то, что не очищает канву при перерисовке. Например если свернуть открыть приложение то все нормально, а потом нажимаешь на кнопку и на экране остается старое изображение наложенное на новое.

Comment: Очевидно что проблема в коде который изменяет значение на TextView. Добавляй его сюда.

Comment: С этой разметкой почти все в порядке, кроме того, что если указываешь вес для виджета - его "весовой" размер должен быть `0dp` и если компоновка линейная, то `RelativeLayout` использовать не рекомендуется. Он более "тяжелый", а возможности его никак не используются. Больше по представленной вами информации сказать нечего. Если проблема в том, что при изменении значения что то не так, то и нужен **код**, как происходит это изменение. С помощью каких экстрасенсорых способностей, вы полагаете, кто то должен угадать, что вы там делаете.

Comment: Если накладывается на новое значит тебе нужно обнулять переменную а не сам TextView. Ты же текст меняшь в Java, вот там и смотри. А лучше сюда скинь код

Comment: Добавил текст в вопрос

Comment: @pavlofff
RelativeLayout используется только для того что бы расположить TextView так что бы он не перекрывал кнопки.
Добавил код в вопрос :)

Comment: @xTIGRx добавил код в вопрос, спасибо что откликнулись :)

Comment: @nekaneka добавил код в вопрос, спасибо что откликнулись :)

Comment: Что значит если ноль то 
 if( m_сounterTextView == null )
        m_сounterTextView = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.PlusMinusOneCounterTextView );

    m_сounterTextView.setText( _newValue.toString() );

Зачем это?. Ты что в адаптере это пишешь? Если нет то зачем ты пересоздаешь ссылку на объект?

Comment: @xTIGRx Если m_сounterTextView  еще не инициализирован - сделать это сейчас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением проблемы будет явное указание цвета фона RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000">
```

Всем спасибо за помощь и советы :)